# If $\alpha$ is an arbitrary simple curve that cuts transversaly a compact surface the set of common points it can be infinity?

Tags: differential-topology, transversality

**MY ATTEMPT:** Let $S^2=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3| x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ be a compact surface. Defining for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ a regular parametrized curve $\alpha_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\left(0, \frac{1}{n}, t \right)$, such that $t\in (-2, 2)$ (for example). Then the union $C=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\alpha_n$ define a simple curve that cuts $S^2$ transversaly into a countable (infinity) quantity of points.

**MY DOUBT:** How can I extend this proof to connected curves?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the curve $x\in (0,1) \mapsto (x,0,\sin \frac 1 x)$ cuts infinitely many times the surface $z=0$, and transversally (even its compact subset $ -1\leqslant x,y\leqslant 1$).

Comment: Yes, yes. I've ploted this situation in Geogebra. Thank you very much

Comment: Usually these things are stated about a compact manifold without boundary  mapping to (or intersecting) a closed submanifold (without boundary). In that case, the intersection must be finite when it's transverse.